# Is it possible to concatnate varibles in Liquid?

Tags: liquid

I have a For Loop. This Loop give me a variable x with the numbers from 1 to n.

At the same Time I have 2 to n*2 variables: {{Mov1}}, {{Mov2}}, {{Mov3}}, .... , {{Movn}}.  {{Type1}}, {{Type2}}, {{Type3}}, .... , {{Typen}}.

Is it possible to fetch {{Mov1}} and {{Type1}} in the first Loop iteration, then {{Mov2}} and {{Type2}} in the second, and so on? I can't get the variables explicitly, so I'm trying to link them to the iteration variable.

I would say that this should be possible, but can't see how it is done in Liquid

Comment: Post your actual code please to see if someone can help you it's hard to understand from the post.

Comment: Easiest way to concatenate variables in liquid us using the capture tag https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/capture